# Как отменить анимацию когда input пустой

Tags: angularjs, анимация, angular2

Вообщем проблема, у меня есть Angular 2 анимация

```
trigger('focusPanel', [
    state('inactive', style({
         transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active', style({
        transform: 'translateX(535px)'
    })),

    transition('inactive=>active', animate('600ms', keyframes([
    style({
    transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)'
  }),style({
     opacity: 1,
     transform: 'translate3d(325px, 0, 0)'
  }),style({
    transform: 'translate3d(420px, 0, 0)'
  }),style({
    transform: 'translate3d(550px, 0, 0)'
  }),style({
    transform: 'translate3d(525px, 0, 0)'
  }),style({
    transform: 'translate3d(540px, 0, 0)'
  }),style({
    transform: 'translate3d(525px, 0, 0)'
  }),style({
    transform: 'translate3d(535px, 0, 0)'
  }),
```

функция

```
toggleMove(){
        this.state = (this.state === 'inactive' ? 'active': 'inactive');
}
```

при клике на submit input уезжает, но проблема в том что когда он пустой анимация все равно срабатывает. 
Вопрос как сделать чтобы только при заполненом input срабатывала анимация.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input ... [@focusPanel]="state" [@.disabled]="myInputIsEmpty">
```

https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disable-animations

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!